# Compile-time created class is shown as non-existent in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, annotation-processing

**Motivation**:

I'd like to try if compile-time annotation processing fits my problem. It needs to work out of the box, no compiler arguments etc.

---

**Current state**:

I have:

- The annotation
- An annotation processor
- A .jar containing both of these and a javax.annotation.processing.Processor file containing the [FQCN](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/FQCN) of my processor in META-INF/services

What should happen:

- It should autodetect the processor
- It should process the annotation and create a new class (WiredAnnotated)
- I should be able to use this class in one step of compilation (not multiple phases)
- I wan't the editor to accept this class is generated (e.g. [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/) manages this as well)

What actually happens:

- It autodetects the processor
- It creates a new class (in out/production/*/generated/)
- I am able to use this class

  - The source code looks right
  - When decompiling it looks ok too
- The editor cannot resolve the class (see screenshot)

What I tried:

- Restarting IntelliJ
- Invalidating caches
- Checking for output of the annotation processor

Screenshot:

[image]

When compiling, it actually works as expected. I guess it has something to do with inspecting the wrong directories.

Does anyone have an idea/clue on what I'm doing wrong? Did I miss information which could help you help me?

Thanks in advance, Till

Comment: @vikingsteve: Edited the question, please have another look.

Comment: Thanks, question very clear now, but it's way above my pay grade :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to add you `out/production/*/generated/` to projects source folder. So, IntelliJ will know about your generated classes.

You can make it via Right click on directory > Mark directory as source root.

or

Project structure (F4) > Modules > Sources tab > Source folders should contain all directories with your source codes, generated one inludes.

In android there is a `gen` dir in root folder, but notice, it glows blue or green which means it marked as Source folder, it is also visible in Project structure > Modules. It contains `R`, `BuildConfig` and `Manifest`.

Comment: Sure, I tried this, but I also needed to uncheck some other option, to *unexclude* the build-output-folders. But all that matters is: **It works**!