# IntelliJ can't find generated sources when used in same module

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, autofactory

I'm using annotation processors of [Google's AutoFactory](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/factory). I annotated `SomeClass` with `@AutoFactory` and referenced `new SomeClassFactory().create()` somewhere else in that same module.

#### Maven configuration:

I added the necessary dependency in Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auto.factory</groupId>
        <artifactId>auto-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta2</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

When running `$ mvn clean compile` I see that `target/generated-sources/annotions/somepackage/SomeClassFactory` is created and the module compiles without errors.

#### IntelliJ configuration:

- `Reimport all maven modules`
- `Preferences` -> `Annotation Processors` -> `Enable annotation processing`
- `Rebuild Project`

This should be enough in my version of IDEA (`v14.1.4`) if my understanding is correct.

[image: Compiler Preferences]
[image: Project Structure]

I also performed the following steps:

- Verified that `generated-sources` folder is added as a source in `Project Structure`
- Verified that Maven preference `Generated sources folders` is set to `Detect automatically`
- Verified that source is actually generated upon Rebuild (deleted `target` folder first to be sure it's generated by IntelliJ)
- Try to disable `Exclude output paths` in Project Structure, as suggested by [@tilpner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19863055/741217)
- Invalidate caches and restart
- Delete `.idea` folder and `.iml` files
- Experiment with different settings for `Phase to be used for folders update` in `Preferences` -> `Maven` -> `Importing`

#### Problem:

After performing all these steps, the generated class doesn't show up in the project explorer. In fact, the entire `target` directory is nowhere to be seen. Compilation fails with `cannot find symbol: SomeClassFactory` 
and `new SomeClassFactory().create()` is marked in red in the editor, while Maven generates and compiles without any problems.

I'm out of options myself and any help or suggestions would be very welcome!

**Update:** when I comment the code that causes the compilation error, IntelliJ prints this warning in the compilation messages: `Warning:Output path /Users/.../target/generated-sources/annotations intersects with a source root. Only files that were created by build will be cleaned.`

Comment: Try this solution, it may resolve your issue.
[click here for the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47278829/7855267)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got help from Jetbrains support and the problem turned out to be a preference for excluded files. There are two places where these are configured:

> Please check that folders/files are not excluded in `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Excludes` and the file/folder pattern in not listed in `Preferences > Editor > File Types -> Ignored files and folders`

In my case `target` was included in the ignored files and folders list in `Editor` > `File Types`.

Then there was still a compilation issue, which I solved by throwing away the IDEA project files and creating the project again.